# jQuery.load isn't working for me in IE

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }
</style>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Footer navigation:</b>
<div id="new-nav"></div>
<div id="new-nav1"></div>

<script type="application/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("#new-nav").load("test/index1.php");
$("#new-nav").ajaxStop(function(){
   $("#new-nav1").load("test/index1.php")
}); 
}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to use jQuery `load` to part load my two PHP pages into my main page, but it works in Firefox, not in IE - where is the problem?

Comment: are you using any other plugins??

Comment: Why did you remove the code from the question?! Having code in the question is a Good Thing, and it's the only reason I was able to identify the problems for you. I've put it back.

Answer (score 7):

**Two problems:**

#### `type`

Your `type` is wrong:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/axoke5) (not working in IE)

It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

...or you can just leave it off, as all major browsers (and probably all minor ones) default to JavaScript, and the latest standard-in-progress reflects this by [making JavaScript officially the default](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script).

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/axoke5/2) (working in IE)

---

#### Infinite loop

That may may well create an infinite loop, because the second `load` call will trigger your `ajaxStop` handler when it completes, causing another `load`, causing another `ajaxStop`, etc.

Instead, try:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://jsbin.com/esili3",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#new-nav").html(data);
      $("#new-nav1").load("http://jsbin.com/ixiko5");
    }
  });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/axoke5/7)

Comment: @crowder , any reason why you said don't shout to the person who posted this question...asking just casually

Comment: @gov: The title was originally in all caps.